# Relacionamento entre tabelas no MySQL

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados

Estou criando um site e estou com um problema nele, nesse site eu irei exibir alguns personagens do jogo *League of Legends* e mostrarei qual personagem é forte ou fraco em relação aos outros, por exemplo o Personagem 1 é forte contra o personagem 2 mas é fraco contra o personagem 3.

Eu possuo a tabela `CAMPEOES` e nela cadastrados:
`| champ_id | champ_nome | champ_descricao | champ_avatar |`

Para criar essa relação eu irei precisar criar outra tabela para relacioná-los ou posso fazer algo na própria tabela de campeões já que ela possui as informações que vou precisar que são `champ_nome` e `champ_avatar`.

Os personagens podem estar relacionados a vários outros personagens ao mesmo tempo.

Comment: Acredito que seja melhor criar outra estrutura. Ou uma tabela, ou duas. Uma tabela (champ_id_principal, champ_id_secundario, relacao), onde champ_id_principal é forte ou fraco em relacao ao secundario, por isso o campo relacao. Ou duas tabelas. "tbl_fortes", champ_prin, champ_sec. onde o principal é mais forte que o sec, e a mesma ideia para a "tbl_fracos". Fica a seu critério, é bem questão de opinião o que você está querendo...

Comment: Ok entendi, mas nao estou conseguindo pensar em como ficaria o `SELECT` para exibir a informação, essa questão de relacionamento entre tabelas me confunde bastante.

Comment: Depende de qual estrutura você quer seguir... você pode definir ela e editar sua pergunta colocando as tabelas, que alguém ajudará a montar seu select :)

Comment: Você está tornando a pergunta ampla por estar fazendo várias perguntas em um único tópico. A princípio você queria saber como fazer a relação de duas tabelas, agora está perguntando sobre a forma de realizar o *select*. Então a questão sobre o relacionamento das tabelas foi resolvido? O problema agora é somente o *select*?

Comment: Sim Renan, desculpe por este inconveniente o problema do relacionamento foi resolvido agora estou tentando descobrir como seria o SELECT correto para trazer os nomes dos campeoes. não achei que era correto criar outra pergunta para resolver uma pergunta relacionada.

Comment: @FelipeDumont Você pode postar a resolução como resposta nessa pergunta, dando detalhes de como resolveu o problema de modo a ser útil para outros usuários que passem por situações iguais ou semelhantes a sua. Você pode marcar a sua própria resposta como aceita. E então o assunto do *select* poderia ser discutido em uma nova pergunta.

Comment: Ok Renan Farei isso Obrigado.

Comment: Neste caso eu entendo que o problema é o mesmo, e caberia uma edição na pergunta sobre o select. Se aparecerem novas respostas com uma melhor proposta de organização, a pergunta separada fica obsoleta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O Problema foi resolvido o Rafael me ajudou a pensar em como ficaria a lógica das tabelas que serão relacionadas ficando assim...

Decidi criar duas tabelas que são elas `campeao_forte` e `campeao_fraco` ambas possuem a estrutura `.._principal` e `.._secundario`
sendo que na tabela `campeao_forte` em sua coluna `.._primario` será gravado o ID do campeão que é forte e na secundária será gravado o ID do campeão que é fraco contra o primário.

O mesmo ocorre na tabela `campeao_fraco` porém o primário indica que o campeão é fraco contra o secundário.

Comment: Felipe, se possível marque a sua resposta como aceita. :)

Comment: Eu nao consegui aceitar a resposta ao clicar em aceitar me retorna a mensagem "Você pode aceitar sua resposta em 2 dias"